# Jquery hasclass not working

Tags: jquery

I can see in firefox that ul.ulsearch has the class of hidden, but it doesn't work, why?

```
$('.ulsearch').click(function() {
    if ($('.ulsearch').hasclass("hidden")) {
        $('.lisearch').fadeIn(100);
    }  
});
```

Comment: Please learn to use the StackOverflow Markdown Syntax so we can read your code.

Comment: in jQuery 1.4 I found a bug related with hasClass() http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/5867, maybe related

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK it's **hasClass**, not hasclass